# Is it possible to use luks on output in bash?

Tags: bash, encryption, luks

Can I use `luks` (as in OpenSSL) to encrypt bash output?

e.g with OpenSSL:

`echo "test" | openssl .....`

Can I do that with Luks/Cryptsetup in some way? Like this:

`echo "test" | Luks...`

Comment: @dr_2 thanks for helping me edit it :thumbsup:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LUKS is not a command, it is name of a technology and/or metadata format so no, you can't use LUKS for encrypting strings. Same applies for `cryptsetup` which is only a userspace tool (library) for configuring and managing the LUKS/dm-crypt devices and doesn't do the encrypting itself -- data written/read to/from the device is encrypted by the device mapper crypto plugin in kernel using the kernel crypto API, cryptsetup only tells kernel to create such device and provides encryption key for it (and also takes care of key management) everything else happens in device mapper.

If you only want to use `cryptsetup` in a non-interactive way to create an encrypted device, that is of course possible:

```
printf %s "$password" | cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdxY -
```

and similarly for unlocking the device

```
printf %s "$password" | cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdxY name -
```

and then you can write your data to `/dev/mapper/name` and close it afterwards using `cryptsetup close name`.

You can create a disk image and use it directly (so `cryptsetup luksOpen disk.img name` instead of using a block device), but to actually encrypt something you still need to write it to the created device mapper device.

Comment: Read your post, okay - (I should've formatted the 2nd test a bit better, )So there are no way of creating a luks-encrypted volume/(or whatever it's called) *From* a bash redirection/output?  (I know, you somehow can (correct me if I'm wrong) make a volume (using e.g dd - I don't really know the details) then, encrypt that,  and I thought - something similar might exist? (If it doesn't obviously it's all okay, nothing we can do :P ) thanks for reply btw!

Comment: I added some information about using `cryptsetup` non-interactively if that is what you want, but that isn't about encrypting the data, just about providing the passphrase using `echo`. The data is encrypted by writing it to the device mapper device.
Maybe I just don't understand your use case, try to describe it a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks so much @VojtechTrefny! this was brilliant.